# What is the most Pythonic way to filter a set?

Tags: python, filter, set

I have list consisting with replacements and I want to do two things:

1. remove duplicates
2. remove all elements by a specific criteria, to be exact I want to remove all elements bigger than a certain value.

I figured I can use filter for 2 and than use set to achieve 1
something like

```
list(set(filter(lambda x:x<C, l)))
```

is there a better/more pythonic/more efficient way?

Comment: I mean the order you encounter elements, sets are unordered so if you want to maintain some order you will be out of luck using a set

Comment: actually in my case the order doesn't matter

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is maybe more "pythonic".

```
filtered = [x for x in set(lst) if x < C]
```

Comment: but in such comprehension won't the set(lst) be calculated for every x?

Comment: @Meni Absolutely not. `for x in set(lst)` creates an iterator after casting once the list to a set, then the list comprehension iterates trough it and stores values if `x < C`.

Comment: is there a reason to use list comprehension instead of set comprehension?

Comment: @Meni I find it makes more sense as the expected output is a list, and I think it is clearer than wrapping a set comprehension with `list()`. However, it does not make much difference, it is up to you.

Answer (score 9):

The best two ways to do them are filter:

```
new_list = list(set(filter(lambda x:x<C, l)))
```

Or set comprehensions (which many would consider more pythonic, and even more efficient):

```
list({x for x in l if x < C})
```

But I guess, if you’re familiar with filter, that you can just stick to it.

Comment: you can do a set comprehension instead of converting your list comp to a set

Comment: Thx I don’t know what I was thinking.

Comment: is using set comprehension better than list comprehension if i am going to convert it to a list anyway?

Comment: It’s definitely shorter and more efficient. In terms of compilation, I’m sure that many people here will pretend like they know which is better, but in the end the difference is literally unnoticeable.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion the most Pythonic way to filter sets, wheevern possible, is by use set operations (Venn diagrams) :

```
A = {0, 1, 4, 5, 8}; 
B = {2, 1, 3, 4, 6}; 

print("Union :", A | B) 

print("Intersection :", A & B) 

print("Difference :", A - B) 

print("Symmetric difference :", A ^ B)
```

another example when you just want to  remove value 5 from set A you just type:

```
A - {5,}
```

and as in this question if you need to filter for grater values than C you just type "containment check" operator "in" which in Python code executes sets.**contains**() magic method (magic method shouldn't be called directly that's why you use "in"):

```
{x for x in l if x > C}
```