# Remove substrings inside a list with better than O(n^2) complexity

Tags: python, string, algorithm, list

I have a list with many words (100.000+), and what I'd like to do is remove all the substrings of every word in the list.

So for simplicity, let's imagine that I have the following list:

```
words = ['Hello', 'Hell', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Ban', 'Peter', 'P', 'e']
```

The following output is the desired:

```
['Hello', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Peter']
```

- `'Hell'` was removed because it is a substring of `'Hello'`
- `'Ban'` was removed because it is a substring of `'Banana'`
- `'P'` was removed because it is a substring of `'Peter'`
- `'e'` was removed because it is a substring of `'Hello'`, `'Hell'`,
  `'Apple'`, and so on.

**What I've done**

This is my code, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way than these nested comprehensions.

```
to_remove = [x for x in words for y in words if x != y and x in y]
output = [x for x in words if x not in to_remove]
```

How can I improve the performance? Should I use `regex` instead?

Comment: you could use a lambda as a filter. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33944647/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-filter-a-set/33944663

Comment: Iterate on words while updating a set of all (unique) substrings, then skip words when they are in this set.

Comment: Just like a homework: select the items in the array that aren't contained by another items.

Comment: Related: [Ukkonen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukkonen%27s_algorithm).  Answerers, please refrain from adding yet another answer with a slightly different way of doing this in O(n^2).

Comment: Related: [Python - Remove any element from a list of strings that is a substring of another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720199/python-remove-any-element-from-a-list-of-strings-that-is-a-substring-of-anothe)

Comment: @jpp This is more than *related* in my eyes.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, possibly, but the question is about performance. I can't see any obviously better algorithms. Maybe it would have been better for OP to offer a bounty on that question with specific reference to performance.

Comment: Since the OP has already an O(n^2) solution, and all the solutions on the proposed dupe are bad, that other question unlikely to help them - this should not be closed.

Comment: @wim So we should have two (almost) identical questions, then? All the answers posted here could be posted over there instead if the question was closed, so what's the problem? But if you're not happy with that, maybe you should vote to close the other question as a dupe of this one?

Comment: @Aran-Fey The other question asks for a _simple_ way to do it. This question asks for a more efficient approach, and has the algorithm tag. I don't think they are duplicates either way. Folks can golf their favorite O(n^2) over on the other question.

Comment: What's the result of `["Banana", "Banana"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@wim is correct.

Given an alphabet of fixed length, the following algorithm is linear in the overall length of text.  If the alphabet is of unbounded size, then it will be `O(n log(n))` instead.  Either way it is better than `O(n^2)`.

```
Create an empty suffix tree T.
Create an empty list filtered_words
For word in words:
    if word not in T:
        Build suffix tree S for word (using Ukkonen's algorithm)
        Merge S into T
        append word to filtered_words
```

Answer (score 2):

Build the set of all (unique) substrings first, then filter the words with it:

```
def substrings(s):
    length = len(s)
    return {s[i:j + 1] for i in range(length) for j in range(i, length)} - {s}


def remove_substrings(words):
    subs = set()
    for word in words:
        subs |= substrings(word)

    return set(w for w in words if w not in subs)
```

Comment: You are on the right track but you have a failure mode (e.g. input `['ab', 'abc']` will collect `'ab'` in the result.

Comment: Oh yes indeed. Then we must build the substrings set before looping on words again. Thanks.

Comment: You mean duplicates in result? Then a set comprehension instead of list comprehension haha :)

Comment: If one of the words is very long, there will be `O(n^2)` substrings, and then the algorithm won't be as fast as asked.  However this is a good solution for a very long list of small words.

Answer (score 0):

Note that using `for` is slow in python in general, (you may use numpy arrays or NLP package), aside from that, how about this:

```
words = list(set(words))#elimnate dublicates
str_words = str(words)
r=[]
for x in words:
    if str_words.find(x)!=str_words.rfind(x):continue
    else:r.append(x)
print(r)
```

as I am answering here, I don't see a reason why c++ wouldn't be an option

Comment: My mind is blown. This is actually the fastest solution _by a long shot_. In my tests, this is showing to be 4 times as fast as the 2nd best solution posted here. (Of course it doesn't work well if any of the input words contain quotes or any other characters that'll be escaped by `repr`, but as long as the input is limited to letters, I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work.)

Comment: A solution that only works with a subset of input is not a solution at all.  –1.

Comment: Also has a bug, try with input `['a', 'b', 'a']`.

Comment: True, it doesn't work if there are duplicate words in the input. That's easily fixed with a `set` call though.

Comment: @Aran-Fey it worked when  quations  is used (even if it appeared like: \'  or /"  it still gives true, .. , I wander if the OP thinks it has bugs in some cases!! (on his list)

Comment: [Fails with quotation marks and other non-alphanumeric characters.](https://ideone.com/FuAH9A)

Comment: @user2357112 you mean a single double quatation with no other letters or characters,.. I agree with that , .. but how about another encoding like chinese letters or arabic,(where python cannot render them) .. this cannot end, so I safely assumed a simple case in my answer....

Answer (score -1):

You can sort your data by length, and then use a list comprehension:

```
words = ['Hello', 'Hell', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Ban', 'Peter', 'P', 'e']
new_words = sorted(words, key=len, reverse=True)
final_results = [a for i, a in enumerate(new_words) if not any(a in c for c in new_words[:i])]
```

Output:

```
['Banana', 'Hello', 'Apple', 'Peter']
```

Comment: Will the slicing at `new_words[:i]` not slow down the operation?  It has to build a new list, I believe.

Comment: If the slicing is really a problem, it can be replaced with `itertools.islice`.