# Remove entries in a python set based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, kdtree

I used scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_pairs() which returned a python set of tuples.
Let's say, this is the output:

```
set1 = {(2, 3), (4, 5), (1, 6), (6, 7), (3, 8), (6, 8)}
```

Next, I want to erase all the tuples in the set which do not fulfill the condition

```
arr = [6, 7]
tuple[0] in arr or tuple[1] in arr
```

What would be the most elegant/fast/pythonic way? Should I maybe convert to a numpy array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most Pythonic way to filter a set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33944647/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-filter-a-set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over and check every tuple in `set1`, you can do that using a [**set comprehension**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), and [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> set1 = {(2, 3), (4, 5), (1, 6), (6, 7), (3, 8), (6, 8)}
>>> arr = [6, 7]
>>> set2 = set(arr)  # convert to set for O(1) lookup time
>>> set3 = {t for t in set1 if any(x in set2 for x in t)}
>>> set3
{(6, 7), (6, 8), (1, 6)}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this would be to iterate through the set and create an array for the elements which fulfill the conditions and then convert the array to a set.

This can be done with a one-line solution such as:

```
set2 = set([a for a in set1 if a[0] not in key and a[1] not in key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for

```
filtered = [x,y for x,y in set1 if (x,y) == (6,7)]
```

or try using lambda for complex filters.

Answer (score 0):

Without converting your data to *numpy* arrays, this is how I would address this problem:

```
set1 = {(2, 3), (4, 5), (1, 6), (6, 7), (3, 8), (6, 8)}
arr = [6, 7]

filtered = list(filter(lambda xy: bool(set(xy) & set(arr)), set1))
```

If the length of the elements within *set1* grows considerably and you decide to use *numpy*, then I would just change the sets intersection for *numpy*'s **[intersect1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html#numpy-intersect1d)**

If instead the length of *set1* grows, then I suggest you take a look on this other [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422690/filtering-a-numpy-array) to see how you can filter a numpy array.